# How to find the number of multiplications for x^63 using the exponent recursive function and how to justify it?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

How would I go about justifying this algorithm is O(log n)?

```
public static long exponentiation(long x, int n){

    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0){
        x = exponentiation(x, n / 2);
        return x * x; 
    }
    else{
        return x * exponentiation(x, n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply add a counter in the method, call it once, and then check the value of the counter afterwards. This would guarantee correctness and be (empirically) justified for free.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you came to the answer of the multiplication steps being 11? Can you walk me through the steps?

Comment: What @BeUndead said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each recursive call to method `exponentiation` is a *multiplication step*. Hence you need to count the number of recursive calls. There are several ways to achieve this. I chose to add another parameter to the method.

```
public static long exponentiation(long x, int n, int count) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println("steps = " + count);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0) {
        x = exponentiation(x, n / 2, count + 1);
        return x * x; 
    }
    else {
        return x * exponentiation(x, n - 1, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Here is the initial call to method `exponentiation`

```
exponentiation(2, 63, 0);
```

When I run the above code, the following is printed

```
steps = 11
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `static` counter as well (without changing the prototype of the function):

```
public static long counter = 0;

public static long exponentiation(long x, int n){
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0){
        x = exponentiation(x, n / 2);
        counter++;
        return x * x; 
    }
    else{
        counter++;
        return x * exponentiation(x, n-1);
    }
}
```

However, you need to reset the counter before calling the function each time, i.e., set `counter = 0`.

#### Theoretical Analysis

Note that you need to the counter to prove that it is in `O(log(n))`. To prove the complexity, just you need to find the complexity term by looking at the flow of the code. Suppose `T(n)` is the number of multiplications for computing `x^n`. So, based on the written code, `T(n) = T(n/2) + 1`, if `n` is even, and `T(n) = T(n-1) + 1`, if `n` is odd. Now, at least in one of two consecutive recursions, input `n` is even. Therefore, at most `2 log(n)` is required to reach to `n = 0`. Because, for each even input, the next input will be halved. So, we can conclude that the algorithm is in `O(log(n))`.